# d3js multi-line chart is being drawn off the plot area - is update pattern to the issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I've created a multi line chart that is plotting multiple groups of pairs of lines - although I'm not sure if I'm updating the lines correctly or in the most d3 way. What is the correct way to to update existing paths with new data coming through? I've used setinterval to simulate new data arriving.

Other issue I have is that the lines are all drawn not on the actual plot area - they seem to start off to the left of the chart. I've checked the x scale and it has the correct dates from the data, so not sure what is going on really and would value some input. I've tired manually setting the x domain to some hard coded dates and it shifts the lines over but surely this isn't right. I am not sure if it's something to do with the updating stuff as the x and y scale get updated but the paths don't.

So my questions are because I'm not sure if they are related to each other:

1) How to fix the drawing of the lines?

2) Am I doing the updates correctly for both lines?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <title>my plots!</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <!-- load the d3.js library -->
  <style>
    /* set the CSS */
    
    body {
      font: 12px Arial Bold;
    }
    
    .graph-svg-component {
      background-color: white;
    }
    
    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }
    
    .rawline {
      fill: none;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }
    
    .raw2line {
      fill: none;
      stroke-width: 10px;
      opacity: 0.4;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> plot</h1>
  <div id="graphDiv"></div>
  <!-- css FIll none is important so that its just a line and not an area -->

  <script>
    var data_set = [{
        'Asset_Date': '2009-03-23',
        'Raw': 25,
        'Raw2': 25,
        'Asset': 'A'
      },
      {
        'Asset_Date': '2009-03-24',
        'Raw': 28,
        'Raw2': 25.4,
        'Asset': 'A'
      },
      {
        'Asset_Date': '2009-03-25',
        'Raw': 26,
        'Raw2': 25.37,
        'Asset': 'A'
      },
      {
        'Asset_Date': '2009-03-26',
        'Raw': 22,
        'Raw2': 25.03,
        'Asset': 'A'
      },
      {
        'Asset_Date': '2009-03-27',
        'Raw': 19,
        'Raw2': 24.42,
        'Asset': 'A'
      },
      {
        'Asset_Date': '2009-03-28',
        'Raw': 23,
        'Raw2': 24.28,
        'Asset': 'A'
      },
      {
        'Asset_Date': '2009-03-23',
        'Raw': 30,
        'Raw2': 30,
        'Asset': 'B'
      },
      {
        'Asset_Date': '2009-03-24',
        'Raw': 31,
        'Raw2': 33,
        'Asset': 'B'
      },
      {
        'Asset_Date': '2009-03-25',
        'Raw': 32,
        'Raw2': 34,
        'Asset': 'B'
      },
      {
        'Asset_Date': '2009-03-26',
        'Raw': 33,
        'Raw2': 35,
        'Asset': 'B'
      },
      {
        'Asset_Date': '2009-03-27',
        'Raw': 34,
        'Raw2': 36,
        'Asset': 'B'
      },
      {
        'Asset_Date': '2009-03-28',
        'Raw': 37,
        'Raw2': 39,
        'Asset': 'B'
      }
    ]

    var margin = {
      top: 30,
      right: 50,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 50
    };

    var svgWidth = 800;
    var svgHeight = 800;
    var graphWidth = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
    var graphHeight = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, graphWidth]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([graphHeight, 0]);

    var z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10); // for colours

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x).ticks(10);
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y).ticks(20);

    // Need to create the lines manually for each bit of data
    // Line for raw value
    var line = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.Asset_Date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.Raw);
      });

    // Line for raw2 value
    var line2 = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.Asset_Date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.Raw2);
      });

    // Creates the SVG area within the div on the dom 
    // Just doing this once 
    var svg = d3.select("#graphDiv")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", svgWidth)
      .attr("height", svgHeight)
      .attr("class", "graph-svg-component");
    var g = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function() {
        svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
      }));


    // // Add the X Axis
    g.append("g").attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + graphHeight + ")")
      .call(xAxis);
    // Text label for x axis 
    g.append("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("timeseries dates")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (graphWidth / 2) + " ," + (graphHeight + margin.top) + ")");

    // // Add the Y Axis
    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);
    // text label for the y axis
    g.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
      .attr("x", 0 - (graphHeight / 2))
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("price points");

    function drawGraph(data_set) {
      console.log('Dataset contains', data_set.length, 'item(s)')

      data_set = data_set.map(function(d) {
        return {
          Asset: d.Asset,
          Asset_Date: parseDate(d.Asset_Date),
          Raw: +d.Raw,
          Raw2: +d.Raw2
        };
      });

      // Keying data on Asset for easy grouping
      var nested = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {
          return d.Asset;
        })
        .entries(data_set);

      // Set X domain to min and max of date from data set
      min1 = d3.min(nested, function(d) {
        return d3.min(d.values, function(d) {
          return d.Asset_Date;
        });
      });
      max1 = d3.max(nested, function(d) {
        return d3.max(d.values, function(d) {
          return d.Asset_Date;
        });
      });
      console.log(min1)
      console.log(max1)
      console.log(d3.extent([min1, max1]))
      x.domain(d3.extent([min1, max1]));

      y.domain([
        d3.min(nested, function(d) {
          return d3.min(d.values, function(d) {
            return Math.min(d.Raw, d.Raw2);
          });
        }),
        d3.max(nested, function(d) {
          return d3.max(d.values, function(d) {
            return Math.max(d.Raw, d.Raw2);
          });
        })
      ]);

      // for colours - by asset as they are grouped 
      var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)
        .domain(d3.keys(nested[0])
          .filter(function(key) {
            return key === "Asset";
          }));


      // Update the axis
      svg.selectAll('.x.axis').call(xAxis);
      svg.selectAll('.y.axis').call(yAxis);

      // Join data 
      var city = svg.selectAll(".city").data(nested, function(d) {
        console.log(d);
        return d.key;
      })
      console.log(city)
      // Remove old elements as needed
      city.exit().transition().duration(750).remove()

      // Add a new group per category we have - aka new elements   
      var cityEnter = city.enter().append("g").attr("class", "city");

      // Add line for raw value 
      cityEnter.append("path")
        .attr("class", "rawline")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("stroke", function(d) {
          return color(d.key);
        })
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          console.log("update rawline path");
          return line(d.values);
        });

      // Add line for raw2 value 
      cityEnter.append("path")
        .attr("class", "raw2line")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("stroke", function(d) {
          return color(d.key);
        })
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          console.log("update raw2line path");
          return line2(d.values);
        });

      var t1 = city.transition();
      // Doing the update the lines with new data 

      t1.select(".rawline").attr("d", function(d) {
        return line(d.values);
      });
      t1.select(".raw2line").attr("d", function(d) {
        return line2(d.values);
      });
    }


    // display initial chart
    window.onload = drawGraph(data_set)
    //Push new data every 5 seconds for a specific date
    var h = setInterval(function() {
      data_set.push({
        'Asset_Date': '2009-03-29',
        'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
        'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25),
        'Asset': 'A'
      }, {
        'Asset_Date': '2009-03-30',
        'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
        'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25),
        'Asset': 'A'
      }, {
        'Asset_Date': '2009-03-31',
        'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
        'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25),
        'Asset': 'A'
      }, {
        'Asset_Date': '2009-04-01',
        'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
        'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25),
        'Asset': 'A'
      }, {
        'Asset_Date': '2009-04-02',
        'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
        'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25),
        'Asset': 'A'
      }, {
        'Asset_Date': '2009-04-03',
        'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
        'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25),
        'Asset': 'A'
      });
      console.log('Redrawing')
      drawGraph(data_set);
      clearInterval(h); //doing this so that it doesnt spam - if i uncomment this, it will keep spamming new lines
    }, 5000);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Would really appreciate some help on the above questions - if you need more details - please reach out! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You are doing `select` to update the lines, `select` will only select the first occurrence, replacing it with `selectAll` will solve your problem.
2. As you are using margins for the axis, you can set `translate` to your `.city` group. So when you append that `g`, it would look like this:

   ```
   var cityEnter = city.enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", 0)")
      .attr("class", "city");
   ```

Here is a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wt6vkj82/

Comment: Thanks for replying,  but now it looks like the new incoming data is not being applied to the paths ? @Guillermo Garcia

Comment: @Lakhvir This is the correct answer regarding the margins issue. However, the `selectAll` change is incorrect: your code is working correctly with `select`, since for each group there is just one path of each class. On top of that, `selectAll` doesn't propagate the data.

Comment: Thanks so much @GerardoFurtado! That works. One final issue with this is that if i push new data pieces for a new key, it uses the first color again in the color domain rather than a new one - can you assist with that? I thought to maybe append a hardcoded hex colour for each group I have but there could be 100's so not sure that is the right approach. Thanks in advance :)